# Django: how to use a DB parameter in a default attribute of model field?

Tags: python, django

I have created a (kind of) singleton to put all the app parameters in my database:

```
class SingletonModel(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = 1
        super(SingletonModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        return cls.objects.all().get()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class AppParameters(SingletonModel, models.Model):

    DEFAULT_BALANCE_ALERT_THRESHOLD = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)
    # other parameters...
```

It worked pretty well, until I tried to use one of these parameters in a `default` attribute of a model field:

```
class Convive(models.Model):

    balance_alert_threshold = models.IntegerField(
        default=AppParameters.load().DEFAULT_BALANCE_ALERT_THRESHOLD,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
```

This seemed to work too, but when I use a script to reinitialise local data, the first `manage.py migrate` produce a `DoesNotExist` since my Singleton does not exist yet.
It happens because of a file importing `Convive` model.

How would you solve this?
Is there a way to "delay" the evaluation of the default field?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
After posting this, I think that if my code processes db queries at import time, something may be wrong with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that returns the default value,

```
def get_default_balance_alert_threshold():
    return AppParameters.load().DEFAULT_BALANCE_ALERT_THRESHOLD
```

then use that method as your default.

```
class Convive(models.Model):
    balance_alert_threshold = models.IntegerField(
        default=get_default_balance_alert_threshold,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Comment: Simple and clever, thanks! That solved both problem (DoesNotExist error and potential DB queries run at import time)